# Copying form data in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a Wordpress site where I need to pass form input data from a small form to a larger form on a separate page.

The small form contains 3 fields and is in the header.php file of the site:

```
<form role="form" class="formsmall">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  </div>

<a href="http://poweredby-staging.fundrazr.com/?page_id=253#register"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Get Started</button></a>
</form>
```

The large form is a Mailchimp form and the code is posted in a Wordpress page...

I know you have to use jQuery or javascript to copy the data but I have tried several methods and none have worked. Please help!

Comment: to be more specific, on button click I would like the users first name, last name, and email to be copied to the large form

Comment: use **$_POST**... Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Remove text **

Small example:

```
 <input class="required" id="mce-FNAME" type="text" name="FNAME" value="<?php print (!empty($_POST['FNAME']) ? $_POST['FNAME'] : ''); ?>">
```

**EDIT 2:**

- adding form-submit and form-action and change the button (remove the link and change the button-type)
- adding **name**-attributes on the form

  ```
  <form role="form" action="http://poweredby-staging.fundrazr.com/?page_id=253#register" method="post" class="formsmall">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" name="FNAME" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" name="LNAME" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="EMAIL" />
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Get Started</button>
  ```

Comment: ok thanks, that is what I am trying for. I added the php code in your example to the large form, I had to use a plugin to make the php work on the wordpress page. So what should I add to my button for $_POST to work? sorry I am new to this...

Comment: misunderstand you. which button do you mean?

Comment: the "get started" button just links to the other form.<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Get Started</button>         I'm not sure how to make it post the values to the other form.

Comment: change **type="button"** to **type="submit**. wait im give you an HTML Update.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. I tried that but it's not working... when I click the button nothing happens now, doesn't link to the other page and when I manually navigate there the value isn't copied. Any other suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Yeah i found the problem: The **<input>'s** on your small form hav'nt a **name**-Attribute. Wait 5 secs, im update that. DONE.